# Windows 7 phone and Outlook: Always-on notification beep for emails matching a specific message rule?

Tags: outlook

Our ASP.NET application uses ELMAH to send error notifications via email.  When this happens, I get the email on my phone and am notified via tone that a new email has arrived.  However, at night, I turn my phone's volume off so I don't get woken up by errors that result in the user playing around with the query string.  Some errors, though, I want to know about and even wake me up at night.  Is there some way that, for certain emails, I can have Outlook on my Windows 7 phone ignore my phone's volume setting and make a tone even if I have it set to only vibrate?

Comment: Whilst not a direct solution, one option would be to develop an app of your own for the error alerts (rather than rely on email) and do it via push notifications; in this way, you wouldn't need to disable the volume, which I would imagine no application can interfere with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is (currently, which I think includes the upcoming Windows Phone 8 version of the OS) no option that enables you to do what you want with selective notification sounds for emails based on the content or other properties of a received email. When volume is off, it is off.